# connect raspi 3B with ethercat coupler

Tags: connection

I am new user and trying to connect raspi 3B with codesys and ethercat coupler (Kuhnke FIO coupler).

this is how I connect them:

My labtop is connected through the raspi USB with USB/RJ45 adapter
the ethercat coupler is connected the raspi through RJ45(I did static address for eth1: 192.168.137.100)
CODESYS Control for Raspberry Pi SL is installed on codesys but cannot find the raspi

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig

eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr b8:27:eb:68:8e:a6
inet addr:169.254.72.156 Bcast:169.254.255.255 Mask:255.255.0.0
etc......

eth1 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:00:00:00:35:54
inet addr:192.168.137.100 Bcast:192.168.137.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
etc......

I don't understand...
can you help please?

Papi

Comment: "I don't understand" neither do we! What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to use the raspi as a plc connected to ethercat coupler.